# terminal, tail, check 2 logs separated, with grep (or some option)

Tags: bash, grep, tail

need check 2 logs in one window. I know there is `multitail`, but how can I use this with some pipe (`grep` or some filtering for example)?

Example.

```
multitail A.log (B.log | grep 193.85.23.66)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I had just bad syntax, there is `-e` parameter and rule/filter must be **BEFORE** processed file.

```
multitail A.log -e '193.85.23.66' B.log
```